# Colors of Profile GPU bars on Android M

Tags: android, performance, gpu, android-6.0-marshmallow

When setting Profile GPU rendering developer feature to "On screen as bars" I used to see bars with blue, purple, red, and orange colors on Android Lollipop as described [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/performance/profile-gpu-rendering/index.html).

But on Android Marshmallow these bars consist of seven different colors: dark green, medium green, light green, blue, light blue, red, and orange.

[image: Profile GPU on-screen bars on Android M]

I didn't manage to find any information relating these colors on Android Developers. So what do these new colors mean?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't an official documentation yet, but in [this](https://plus.google.com/+AlexLockwood/posts/Yj23fFY7Eon) Google+ post a bunch of Googlers suggest a blog post that is *"really well written and details the changes*".

Quoting relevant part from http://blog.udinic.com/2015/09/15/speed-up-your-app:

> In Marshmallow, more colors were added to indicate more steps, such as
>   Measure/Layout, input handling and others:
>
> [image]
>
> EDIT 09/29/2015: John Reck, a framework engineer in Google, [has added](https://plus.google.com/+AlexLockwood/posts/Yj23fFY7Eon)
>   this information about some of the new colors:
>
> The exact definition of “animation” is everything that’s registered
>   with Choreographer as CALLBACK_ANIMATION. This includes
>   Choreographer#postFrameCallback and View#postOnAnimation which are
>   what’s used by view.animate(), ObjectAnimator, Transitions, etc… And
>   yup, it’s the same thing systrace labels as “animation”.
>
> “misc” is the delay between the vsync’s timestamp and the current
>   timestamp when it was received. If you’ve ever seen logs from
>   Choreographer about “Missed vsync by blabla ms skipping blabla
>   frames”, that now shows up as “misc”. This is the difference between
>   INTENDED_VSYNC and VSYNC in the framestats dump
>   (https://developer.android.com/preview/testing/performance.html#timing-info)

Comment: Your last link in this post is dead. Also, I found some official documentation that seems to match the image you have here: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-gpu.html

Comment: There is official documentation. See my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46926866/878126

Answer (score 2):

I think the next links of Google should help:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VzYkVL1n4M8
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/profile-gpu.html
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/dev-options-rendering.html

The colors mean different things based on the Android version you have.

Android 6.0 and above:

[image]

Android versions 4.x - 5.x :

[image]